# Python Selenium always open an extra window after successfully getting the results

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm working on a project using Python(3.7) and Selenium, in which I'm parsing some information from the web. when I run my program it opens a window in chrome browser and gets the result successfully but after getting the result successfully it every time opens another window for Favicon icon.

Here's what I have tried:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
google_url = "https://www.google.com/search?q={}".format(term) + "&num=" + str(5)
driver.get(google_url)
# time.sleep(3)
driver.implicitly_wait(100)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
result_div = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'g'})

links = []
titles = []
descriptions = []
for r in result_div:
    # Checks if each element is present, else, raise exception
    try:
        link = r.find('a', href=True)
        title = None
        title = r.find('h3')

        if isinstance(title, Tag):
            title = title.get_text()

        description = None
        description = r.find('span', attrs={'class': 'st'})

        if isinstance(description, Tag):
            description = description.get_text()

        # Check to make sure everything is present before appending
        if link != '' and title != '' and description != '':
            links.append(link['href'])
            titles.append(title)
            descriptions.append(description)
    # Next loop if one element is not present
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        continue
```

Comment: i don't see any error.

Comment: your given code is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce the issue in Ubuntu 16.04 using Python 3.5.

I modified the script to close the automatically opened Chrome window using `driver.close()`.

Updated code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import Tag


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
term = "python"
google_url = "https://www.google.com/search?q={}".format(term) + "&num=" + str(5)
driver.get(google_url)
# time.sleep(3)
driver.implicitly_wait(100)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
result_div = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'g'})

links = []
titles = []
descriptions = []
for r in result_div:
    # Checks if each element is present, else, raise exception
    try:
        link = r.find('a', href=True)
        title = None
        title = r.find('h3')

        if isinstance(title, Tag):
            title = title.get_text()

        description = None
        description = r.find('span', attrs={'class': 'st'})

        if isinstance(description, Tag):
            description = description.get_text()

        # Check to make sure everything is present before appending
        if link != '' and title != '' and description != '':
            links.append(link['href'])
            titles.append(title)
            descriptions.append(description)
    # Next loop if one element is not present
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        continue


print(links)
print(titles)
print(descriptions)
driver.close()
```

Installed packages `requirements.txt`:

```
beautifulsoup4==4.7.1
lxml==4.3.4
pkg-resources==0.0.0
selenium==3.141.0
soupsieve==1.9.1
urllib3==1.25.3
```

Output:

```
['https://www.python.org/', 'https://medium.com/@mindfiresolutions.usa/python-7-important-reasons-why-you-should-use-python-5801a98a0d0b', 'https://medium.com/@mindfiresolutions.usa/python-7-important-reasons-why-you-should-use-python-5801a98a0d0b', 'https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/common/handouts/pythoneclipsejava/python.html', 'https://thehelloworldprogram.com/python/why-python-should-be-the-first-programming-language-you-learn/', 'https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-learn-programming-specially-python-by-my-own-self', 'https://bn.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%A6%AA%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%87%E0%A6%A5%E0%A6%A8_(%E0%A6%AA%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%8B%E0%A6%97%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%82_%E0%A6%AD%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B7%E0%A6%BE)', '/search?q=python&num=5&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=OO5BXHlBkMORMM%253A%252CZIk6oEy_LSc-sM%252C%252Fm%252F05z1_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kQhGxHuP5STNIQIF-LojlNusowOFg&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjB4_vOpujiAhWUe30KHWxxCCoQ_B0wEHoECAEQAw#imgrc=OO5BXHlBkMORMM:']
['Welcome to Python.org', 'Python: 7 Important Reasons Why You Should Use Python - Medium', 'Python: 7 Important Reasons Why You Should Use Python - Medium', 'Python Download and Installation Instructions', 'Why Python Should Be The First Programming Language You Learn ...', 'Is it possible to learn programming specially python by my own ...', 'পাইথন (প্রোগ্রামিং ভাষা) - উইকিপিডিয়া - BN-Wikipedia', 'বিবরণ']
['The official home of the Python Programming Language.', None, None, None, None, None, 'পাইথন (Python) একটি বস্তু-সংশ্লিষ্ট (object-oriented) উচ্চস্তরের প্রোগ্রামিং ... পাইথন একটি বহু-প্যারাডাইম প্রোগ্রামিং ভাষা (ফাংশন-ভিত্তিক, বস্তু-সংশ্লিষ্ট ও\xa0...', None]
```